# jQuery ID selectors getting different results in Chrome vs. IE/Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I have a block of jQuery that's working fine in Chrome, but doesn't in Firefox or IE.

Here's the code:

```
//This part works fine
$('#planCompareTable > tbody > tr').each(function() {
    var $row = $(this);
    if ($row.find('td[data-value="f"]').length == ($row.find('td').length-1)) {
        $row.hide();
        var rowName = $row.attr('id');
        $('input[name="'+$row.attr('id')+'"]').prop('checked',false);
        $('input[name="'+$row.attr('id')+'"]').prop('disabled',true);
    }
});
//End part that works fine

//Here's the issue lines
if ($('#planCompareTable > tbody > tr:visible').length == 0) {
    $('input[name="isNoValues"]').val('true');
}
//End issue lines
```

Here's the table it's working off of.

```
<table id="planCompareTable" class="table table-hover table-condensed table-striped" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0">
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr style="display:table-row;" id="TestIDHere" data-plan-detail="t" data-plan-compare="t">
            <td class="fixedLeftColumn" data-toggle="tooltip" data-hasqtip="0" valign="middle" align="center">
                <div class="fieldNameDivIDPart">Deductible (Individual)</div>
            </td>
            <td id="508352_21772" class="508352_plan commonMaxWidth" valign="middle" align="center">
                <div class="commonMaxWidth">$1,500</div>
            </td>
            <td id="508357_21777" class="508357_plan commonMaxWidth" valign="middle" align="center">
                <div class="commonMaxWidth">$500</div>
            </td>
            <td id="508367_21782" class="508367_plan commonMaxWidth" valign="middle" align="center">
                <div class="commonMaxWidth">$750</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display:table-row;" id="TestID2Here" data-plan-detail="t" data-plan-compare="t">
            <td class="fixedLeftColumn" data-toggle="tooltip" data-hasqtip="1" oldtitle="The amount of covered expenses that must be incurred and paid by the insured before benefits become payable by the insurer." title="" valign="middle" align="center">
                <div class="fieldNameDivIDPart">Deductible (Family)</div>
            </td>
            <td id="508352_21772" class="508352_plan commonMaxWidth" valign="middle" align="center">
                <div class="commonMaxWidth">$3,000</div>
            </td>
            <td id="508357_21777" class="508357_plan commonMaxWidth" valign="middle" align="center">
                <div class="commonMaxWidth">$1,000</div>
            </td>
            <td id="508367_21782" class="508367_plan commonMaxWidth" valign="middle" align="center">
                <div class="commonMaxWidth">$1,500</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

For the if statement, on Chrome, I'll get an accurate length count. For Firefox or IE, I get a count of 0, even though there will be numerous visible rows.

EDIT: After looking more in the DOM, if I set breakpoints on my `if ($('#planCompareTable > tbody > tr:visible').length == 0) {` line, Firefox returns 0 and Chrome returns 9 (for my current table I'm working with). If I switch Firefox to instead look for `tr:hidden`, all 9 rows are listed.

I know there are a few things with Firefox/IE that make jQuery do weird things, but I can't figure out what it would be in this case. Any suggestions? Would going to straight JavaScript be simpler here?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: It's really hard to say without seeing what the HTML looks like

Comment: It's more likely that this is simply a caching problem, as far as it working in 1 browser but not the others, rather than jquery being *weird* in some browsers. That or invalid html.

Comment: I deleted my answer because it got down-voted for using "index" and "element" inside of the callback in each instead of using "this". Instead, I'm going to leave this as a comment, since from what someone wrote on there, "this" is supposed to refer to the element itself, but it has been my experience never to use "this" because it can get confused. Using parameters in each method may be more cross-browser compatible.

Comment: @Dan I think it was downvoted because it was looking at the top section, vs. the if statement.

Comment: @ChrisBarr Added the HTML.

Comment: @Dan I downvoted it because the suggestion doesn't make any sense. `this` and `element` in your answer are identical, changing that in this specific case is pointless. If an arrow function or a bound function was in use, sure, that may have fixed it, but that's not the case here.

Comment: @nlake uhm.... there's no data-value in your html...

Comment: @KevinB That's not the problem here. It's relevant because that would typically hide the specific rows, but since there are no rows to be hidden, they should ALL be visible, and work fine w/ the next chunk of code.

Comment: @nlake then what is? if there's no data-value, then the length will be 0. that would indicate chrome is in the wrong here and all the browsers that "aren't working" are working properly.

Comment: @KevinB It's the 2nd block of code, which I've labeled with comments, that is causing the problem.

Comment: Yes, i see that. but nothing in your question supports a problem existing. Prove that a problem exists.

Comment: @KevinB I have. No TRs have data-value attributes, so they will not be hidden. The count of table rows that are hidden is not 0, so it should not be setting isNoValues to True. On Chrome, it works. On Firefox/IE, it breaks into that and sets isNoValues to True.

Comment: use a class instead of show/hide and :visible:hidden, and your problems will go away. It will also be more performant.

Comment: It's likely that for whatever reason, internal to jquery, the :visbile selector in chrome isn't able to properly see that you've hidden the element before a rerender occurs (which can't occur until the callstack is clear. so a setTimeout might fix it too.) Using a class means that the code will be able to immediately see the class change and not need to rely on a rerender.

Comment: Understood, Kevin. Thought it might make a difference. I've always used index and element and thought perhaps it would work around around the browser issue. Thanks for explaining!